# Best practice for two tables in own "row" (e.g. t1:70% | t2:30%), and achieving 100% in each cell, where you can set font size

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I'm using a table to put two tables to one row and fit them to 2 minipages which are set to 70% and 30%:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
  \begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
    TABLE_1
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    TABLE_2
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

I need a better solution, if exists something like CSS in HTML.

My next problem is that I'm using \resizebox to achieve 100% width of each table in each minipage, e.g.:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
  \begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
     \centering
     \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        TABLE_1
     }
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    \centering
     \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        TABLE_1
     }
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

But in this way I can not change the font size. Font size is set automatically according to the width and height of the table in each cell. So sometimes it is big sometimes very small.

Comment: because I'm using R Sweave to put R code to the "tex" (Rnw) files

Comment: Putting \tiny{begin{table} ...... end{table}} does not work well. The font size is getting a little smaller but not in such a way \tiny should work

Comment: The following paste inserts a `tabular` that is exactly as wide as `\textwidth` consisting of two columns spread out in a 70%/30% ratio: http://pastebin.com/gEV3wwdm Not sure whether this is what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is e.g.:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
  \begin{minipage}{.65\textwidth}
  {\tiny
     \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}%
       AAA & BBBB & CCCC  \\
       \hline
       AAA & BBBB & CCCD
     \end{tabularx}%no space between tables
  }
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
     \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}%
       AAA & BBBB & CCCC  \\
       \hline
       AAA & BBBB & CCCD
     \end{tabularx}%no space between tables
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

\hfill helps to make spaces between the two tables. Flush left and right are now also true. Thank you for your suggestions.

Some other problems I had are solve now with this.

Comment: There seems to be very little need for the `minipage`s, as you can specify the width of each `tabularx`.